# Phyloxml: find and replace in a file

Tags: python, biopython, phylogeny

I am trying to edit tip labels in a phyloxml file, so that they consist of only 4 digits. For instance, what I currently have under name in the phyloxml file are the IDs on the left. What I want are the IDs on the right:

```
ACOM042150-PA ACOM
AQUA008971-PA AQUA
AGAP002137-PA AGAP
AARA006802-PA AARA
```

The code I have so far can pluck out the characters I want using replace methods:

```
tree = Phylo.read("GSCGT000003.xml", "phyloxml")
for i, clade in enumerate(tree.find_clades(name=True)):
    print clade.name.replace(clade.name, clade.name[0:4])
```

This will print the required names to the terminal, but I am unsure how to replace within the file, or to write to a new file with the changes. I can write to a new file using `Phylo.write`, but I cannot seem to be able to write the file with changes. Any thoughts? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change the name of each clade and then save the tree to a new file:

```
tree = Phylo.read("GSCGT000003.xml", "phyloxml")

for clade in tree.find_clades(name=True):
    # This changes the clade name to only the first four chars
    clade.name = clade.name[:4]

# At this point all clade names has been changed in-place
Phylo.write(tree, "GSCGT000003_modified.xml", "phyloxml")
```